# Как убрать отступы между картинками?

Tags: html, css

Сбросил все margin-ы, но небольшой отступ всё равно остаётся из-за чего картинка съезжает на другую строчку. Как это исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

html:

```
<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <ul class="example">
             <li><a href="#" class="blue"><img class="col-4" src="slide1.jpg" /></li></a>
             <li><img class="col-4" src="slide1.jpg" /></li>
             <li><img class="col-4" src="slide1.jpg" /></li>
             <div class="w-100"></div>
             <li><img class="col-4" src="slide1.jpg" /></li>
             <li><img class="col-4" src="slide1.jpg" /></li>
             <li><img class="col-4" src="slide1.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
         </div>
```

css:

```
ul.example{
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
ul.example li {
    display: inline;
    height: 500px;
  }
  .example img{
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в CSS - `ul.example {font-size:0;}`

Comment: @UModeL, Да. Всё сработало